# Using puppeteer to screenshot page and using ffmpeg to generate a video from the screenshot images. how to make smoothly video?

Tags: ffmpeg, puppeteer

I wanna record a web page, and generate a video on server.
Here are my steps.
1. using puppeteer to screenshot the page one by one, and i have images;
2. using ffmpeg to generate a video from the images;

Q: I found that puppeteer launch more than one browser, screenshot will slow down. how to make puppeteer screenshot more effective? I use jpeg format, and reduce the quality to 80. If record a web page needs 30s, I make it chunk to reduce time, for example, launching more than one browser to cut down the recording to 2, or 3...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try these packages:

1. https://github.com/tungs/timecut
2. https://github.com/tungs/timesnap

Maybe you can reproduce or use it for videos production.